# Crossfading elements without resorting to position: absolute

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to crossfade two elements so that one replaces the other. Obviously, the appearing element has to be placed into the DOM before it fades in. Without absolute positioning, it moves the other elements out of place, which is what I need to avoid.

Here is a fiddle of the current behaviour. I need the middle boxes to crossfade without the ugly move effect. I could probably enclose both in another container and position them absolutely within that, but is there a more elegant way?

http://jsfiddle.net/b9yKE/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="one">One</li>
    <li id="two">Two</li>
    <li id="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:60px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

.animate-opac {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-out;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}

.hidden {
     display:none;   
}
```

JS:

```
var $new = $('<li id="twohalf">2.5</li>');
var $ul = $('ul');

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#two').toggleClass("animate-opac");
    $new.toggleClass("animate-opac fade");
    $('#two').after($new);

    $('body')[0].offsetWidth;

    $('#two').toggleClass("fade");
    $new.toggleClass("fade");

    $('#two').on("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
         $(this).remove();   
    });
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the element with the new one inside the transition end callback
http://jsfiddle.net/b9yKE/4/

```
$('#two').toggleClass("animate-opac fade").one("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
     $(this).replaceWith( $new );   
});
```

Comment: That works, but the problem is the other element doesn't fade in through the first one, it just appears after the transition is complete.

Comment: Didn't know that CSS transitions fire events to JavaScript, very nice!